# Datatable child row not appearing in first column when in responsive mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here but when I click on the details contro,. the child row is dsiplayed but it pushed to a new column at the end of the data table.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<table id="exp_datatable" class="display ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AccountNumber</th>
            <th>AccountCostCentre</th>
            <th>AccountDepartment</th>
            <th>Narrative</th>
            <th>TransactionAnalysisCode</th>
            <th>TaxType</th>
            <th>TaxCode</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```
<script>   

    $(function() {

        $tepTable = $('#exp_datatable').DataTable ( {
            ajax: { // doing it this way allows me to invoke ajax.reload
                url: '../ajax/transactions.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {action:'get export preview'},
                dataType: 'json',
                dataFilter: function(data){
                    var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                    var dtData =JSON.stringify( {"data": jData});
                    return dtData;
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            columns: [
                        { data: "nom_code" },
                        { data: "account_cost_centre" },
                        { data: "account_dept" },
                        { data: "narrative" },
                        { data: "trans_analysis_code" },
                        { data: "tax_type" },
                        { data: "tax_code" },
                        { data: "amount" }
            ]
        });       
    });


</script>
```

My table looks like this:
[image]

And here it is with the child row displayed:
[image]

I'm really stuck so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you,

Lee

Comment: Are you using the Bootstrap specific DataTables, as can be checked here: https://datatables.net/download/
And do you have the right corresponding Bootstrap version 3/4?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thank you and apologies for my delayed reply. I'm pretty sure that I am including the correct files but maybe some of my other plugin files are conflicting so I will need to test with a blank slate. I will get back to you. Thanks